# Что такое print(*nul[i])?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, матрицы, print

Дорогие друзья!
У меня есть код:

```
a=int(input())
nul=[[0]*a for i in range(a)]
x,y=0,0
for i in range(1,a**2+1):
    nul[x][y]=i
    if x<=y+1 and x+y<a-1:
        y+=1
    elif x<y:
        x+=1
    elif x+y>=a :
        y-=1
    elif x>=y :
        x-=1
for i in range(a):
    print(*nul[i])
```

Он чужой. И я не могу понять, что значит

```
print(*nul[i])
```

Подскажите мне, пожалуйста!

Comment: Например, если в списке `nul[0]` содержится `[1, 2, 3]`, то функция `print(*nul[0])` выведет на экран `1 2 3`.